# Recognize Java EE project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am not Java EE expert. If I have a source code of a huge Java project, how can I determine if this project is a Java EE-based project or just Java/servlets and JSP? Is there some distinguishing feature that says this is a Java EE project?

I have the source code of a project that uses Spring Frame and Hibernate - how can I tell if this is a Java EE-based project?

Comment: If Spring is used, it probably is no J2EE-only project.

Comment: Justed asking if it is J(2)EE based is bit vague and cannot be answered. Check the deployment descriptors (xml files) to identify if e.g. EJB are used. If it contains a WAR, you probably need a servlet container, etc...

Comment: Usually anything that runs on a Java based Server can be considered as J2EE application. Usually J2EE application Source codes will not have a main method. You can search for this and see. But it is not guaranteed because someone may have written a main method for testing purposes.

Comment: Just curious, how did you come by a huge code base without anything to say what kind of a project as well?

Comment: @shazin An application running on tomcat with spring and hibernate is hardly J2EE...

Comment: Note that Java/servlets and JSP is still a part of Java 2 EE, so even if that is all that is used, it is still a Java 2 EE project.

Comment: Java EE (or J2EE) consists of a Collection of technologies (specs) like: EJB, JPA and ... As long as you are using one of them, your application is kind of J2EE application. but some believe if the APP needs a EJB Container (App Server), only then it's a J2EE App. So It depends on your definition.

Comment: @Thihara I think question has said nothing about Tomcat and with TomcatEE+ you can run J2EE applications too.

Answer (score 0):

[The Java EE 6 Offical tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/docinfo.html) includes the following topics as Java EE.

1. JavaServer Faces Technology
2. Web Services (JAX-WS and JAX-RS)
3. Enterprise Beans (EJBs)
4. Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI, Spring Context and DI)
5. Persistance (JPA, Hibernate)
6. Security (Container security and Java EE topics)

If your project is fully capable of these technologies. It is definitely a Java EE project. If some parts have these feature while others do not. It can be criticisable.

In my opinion, a Java EE project should be in the form of following architecture. Regardless of the technologies used, it can be counted as Java EE project. If A MVC framework (Struts, JSF or Spring MVC), persistance(JPA, Hibernate) and context, dependency injection exists in the project.

[image]